# How to define a custom theme in angular material as to control the color of the button text?

Tags: css, angularjs, themes, angular-material

Hello I'm using angular material and I've defined a custom theme which I want to use as my accent theme:

```
$mdThemingProvider.definePalette('gold', {
    '50': '#333333',
    '100': '#333333',
    '200': '#333333',
    '300': '#333333',
    '400': '#333333',
    '500': '#FFB000',
    '600': '#FFB000',
    '700': '#FFB000',
    '800': '#FFB000',
    '900': '#FFB000',
    'A100': '#333333',
    'A200': '#FFB000',
    'A400': '#FFB000',
    'A700': '#FFB000',
    'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',
    'contrastDarkColors': ['50', '100',
     '200', '300', '400', 'A100'],
    'contrastLightColors': undefined
  });

$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .accentPalette('gold');
```

I've set up a codepen [here](http://codepen.io/GBora/pen/JGgYYg) where you can see it in action, my problem is that the text for my buttons which have the `md-accent` class is still the standard white and not the black colors I've defined as contrast colours in the theme.

Does anybody know how I need to define my theme so that the black `#333333` is used on the text of the `md-accent` buttons ?

Comment: @Rahul I'm already using the $mdThemingProvider to set my theme as the accent theme what should I do more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. You can change the `contrastDefaultColor` to be `dark` instead of `light`. This controls the default contrast color for all colors in the palette.
2. You can update your `contrastDarkColors` to include `A200` which is the color that the buttons use.

You can read more here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme

Comment: Thanks I took the A200 option and it worked perfectly.